# Adding active class from bootstrap to li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

Hello i want to ask why my code doesn't work. I use ruby on rails with bootsrap and haml.

Here is my javascript code:

```
:javascript
  $(".nav navbar-nav li a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  });
```

And here is my navigation bar's code:

```
%nav.navbar.navbar-inverse
  .container-fluid
    .navbar-header
      %img.image{:alt => "Ruby Logo", :src => "http://www.rossconf.io/images/projects/ruby-2779abad.png"}
      = link_to "Users", users_path, class: 'navbar-brand'
      #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1.collapse.navbar-collapse
    %ul.nav.navbar-nav
      %li
        %a{:href => addresses_path}
          Addresses
          %span.sr-only (current)
      %li
        %a{:href => imports_path}
          Import addresses
          %span.sr-only (current)
      - if current_user     
        %li
          %a{:href => logout_path}
            Logout
            %span.sr-only (current)
      - else
        %li
          %a{:href => login_path}
            Login
            %span.sr-only (current)
```

Any idea why it runs without errors but nothing happens? Active class is not added to li element.

Comment: can you share the generated html

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's a mistake in your code:

It should be:

```
$(".nav.navbar-nav li a").click(function() {
//-----^^-------missed a class selector here and you can see a space too 
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: sadly, but still li element is without class when i go to that tab.

Comment: Use $(this).parent().addClass('active') and check if you can see the class in your dom inspector.

Answer (score 1):

First you miss the joining the class in selector. Second thing is if you are want to add active class when you click link then there is two possible solutions are :-

First Solution is

```
$(".nav .navbar-nav li a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  });
```

Second Solution is :-

```
 $(function() {
     var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
     $(".nav .navbar-nav li a ").each(function(){
          if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
          $(this).addClass("active");
     })
});
```

please tell me if i'm wrong and not meet requirement

Comment: I've tried first solution already because other people told me that. Unfortunately, second solution doesn't work too. Its good to mention that i am working on localhost, but i think problem isn't here. Don't know what to do next...

Comment: please can you tell that you links are changed when you click on menu item.Second solution is valid only if your links  are  changed.

Comment: Please see this answer [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060467/add-active-navigation-class-based-on-url)