# URL without www.domain.com/subpage makes every header link start active

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had to give my links an active state and used a code that gets the second part of the `url` and searches for the `nav li a` element with an `href` equal to the second part of the `url`.

When I go to my site the first like U will be is `www.domain.com` without any `/index.php` or `/contact-us.php`. This is a problem since the second part of my url will be empty and tell all my `a` elements to be active.

When I press on 1 of the header links everything works fine.
This is [the site](http://www.winkelmand.nl) I'm talking about, see it yourself if you want ☺.

**Code:**

```
 $(function () {
        var current = location.pathname;
        //Here
        $('nav li a').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            // if the current path is like this link, make it active
            if ($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1) {
                $this.addClass('selected');
        }
    })
});
```

I found this code from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060467/add-active-navigation-class-based-on-url).

I tried adding the underneath code on the `//Here` spot of above code:

```
if ($this.attr('href') ===  window.location.href){
    $this.attr('href', window.location.href + "/index.php"');
}
```

But as you can see I'm not an expert in coding (yet ☺ ) so I couldn't get this to work. Could someone help me with this or guide me in the right direction?

Comment: You can test `if(current != 'www.domain.com/')`

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui thanks for the quick answer, I added the code to `$this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1 && current !== 'www.domain.nl'` but it didn't work. I tried `domain.nl/` and `domain.nl` but both didn't work.

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui I alerted the `current` and it gave me just `/` so I changed it to `current !== '/'` and it works now :D Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are so close to achieve what you want, but you are missing a test:

[location.pathname](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_pathname.asp) will return only the path after the main URL, means when our URL is `www.domain.com/pageX.php`, the result of `location.pathname` would be `/pageX.php`.

So, when we are on the homepage, our URL is just `www.domain.com/`, the pathname would be just `/`.

```
$(function () {
    var current = location.pathname;
    //Here
    $('nav li a').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        // if the current path is like this link, make it active
        if(current != "/"){ //<== Means we are not in the homepage, current is /pageX...
          if ($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1) {
              $this.addClass('selected');
          }
        }else{
          if ($this.attr('href').indexOf('index.php') !== -1) {
              $this.addClass('selected');
          }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Oh you just did this while I found out. But thanks couldn't do this without your help!

Comment: Btw do you know a way to select the `a` element with the `href = 'index.php'` to make it start selected if `current = '/'`?