# change active li and its active parent li when clicking on link

Tags: jquery

I want to make a menu, and change the class of parent `li` and child `li` when clicking.

When I click on the `li` with no `class="active"`, I want jQuery to add a class on the empty `li` and its child `li` and remove it from the others `li`.

I tried following script but it didn't work for me:

```js
$('.menu .list li > ul > li > a').click(function () {
  $('li').removeClass();
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="/Employee/Profile">
                <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                <span>Profile</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="menu-toggle">
                <i class="material-icons">subject</i>
                <span>Leaves</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="ml-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="/Admin/AllEmployees">Show My Leaves</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/Leaves/RequestForLeave">Request for Leave</a>
                </li>
                
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Please help me to write the script.

Comment: Please show your effort first .

Comment: Sorry for asking incomplete question.....I edited my question please take a look @Shree

Comment: Your code work for nested `a` http://jsfiddle.net/yfhgb49L/ What is problem?

Comment: when I open another page using link, I didn't see active link

Answer (score 0):

You might try this code.

```
<script>
    $('.menu .list li > ul > li > a').click(function () {
       $('.menu .list li').each(function(){ $(this).removeClass() });
       $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: $('.menu .list li > ul > li > a').click(function () {
       $('.menu .list li').each(function(){ $(this).removeClass() });
       $(this).parents().addClass('active');
    });

Comment: try this. not parent. parents

Comment: I tried this one.
and i hope this is that you want 
https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=ARG9TCib0p

Comment: As you are clicking an anchor link , which on click redirect page to another location so this case if you want to add active link on current menu item you will need to check the current url with the menu item and then add active class 

Please check this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060467/add-active-navigation-class-based-on-url

https://medium.com/jquery-code-snippets/add-active-navigation-class-to-menu-item-based-on-url-using-jquery-cc88cea618e9