# How to put if else statement here:

Tags: html, css, if-statement

Here's the code:

```
<a href="http://localhost/ja/" class="current">JP</a><span class="bogo_slash"> / </span><a href="http://localhost/">EN</a>
```

If I select either JP/EN, i want to have an underline below there.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060467/add-active-navigation-class-based-on-url

Answer (score 1):

seeing from your code you just have two static pages. just add

```
<style>
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.current {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
```

and `class="current"` to whichever page you're on

**Edit** : If it's a single page, you can use this javascript

```
<a href="http://localhost/jp" id="jp">JP</a><span class="bogo_slash"> / </span><a href="http://localhost/" id="en">EN</a>
<script>
 var url = window.location.href;
 var link = document.getElementById("jp").getAttribute("href");
 
   if (link == url) {
   document.getElementById("jp").classList.add("current");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("en").classList.add("current");  
  }
</script>
<style>
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.current {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Sorry im new to coding, where should I post this. I have only 1 page which is the header, then the href referring to JP is the link from plugin wordpress